# Python Depth First Search stop when found

Tags: python, python-3.x, depth-first-search

I'm having issues with this. When the grid status of the above coordinates of the searched area == 5, it is meant to stop and move to that position. For some reason it carries on and I have been trying to work out why. I'm assuming it is going to be something obvious with someone else's eyes looking at it!

```
def depthfirstsearch(visited,graph,vertex):
    # Do a depth-first search of all neighbours if found stop.
    moveto(vertex,3)
    visited.append(vertex)
    if (the_maze.grid[vertex[0] - 1][vertex[1]].status) == 5:
        x = vertex[0] - 1
        y = vertex[1]
        moveto((x, y), 0)
        return
    else:
        for neighbour in graph[vertex]:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                depthfirstsearch(visited, graph, neighbour)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you have a recursive function, `return` only returns to the function that called it, not all the way back to the original caller. You'll need to return a success value, and if the value is true (or whatever), check that in the caller and cut off the search by passing the success state back up the call chain instead of continuing spawning other recursive calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns when it finds the target.

```
if (the_maze.grid[vertex[0] - 1][vertex[1]].status) == 5:
    # ..
    return
```

However, it returns `None` and the recursive call doesn't do anything with the fact that it returned:

```
if neighbour not in visited:
    depthfirstsearch(visited, graph, neighbour)
```

If this call to `depthfirstsearch()` finds the target, you'd want the function to return as well, with a positive result. If the call doesn't find it, you'd want it to continue searching.

So instead, you need:

```
if (the_maze.grid[vertex[0] - 1][vertex[1]].status) == 5:
    # ..
    return True
```

And:

```
if neighbour not in visited:
    if depthfirstsearch(visited, graph, neighbour):
        return True
```

And finally, you can rely on the function just returning `None` when it finishes without explicitly returning, but that's a bit ugly. `None` evaluates to `False` as a `bool`, but you can also just `return False` at the end for clarity and type-safeness.

So, the result:

```
def depthfirstsearch(visited,graph,vertex):
    # Do a depth-first search of all neighbours if found stop.
    moveto(vertex,3)
    visited.append(vertex)
    if (the_maze.grid[vertex[0] - 1][vertex[1]].status) == 5:
        x = vertex[0] - 1
        y = vertex[1]
        moveto((x, y), 0)
        # found it, report success
        return True
    else:
        for neighbour in graph[vertex]:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                if depthfirstsearch(visited, graph, neighbour):
                    # found in recursion, report success
                    return True
    # if this point is reached, this call didn't find it anywhere
    return False
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you think it answers your question, please accept the answer, so that the question shows as answered and people know it no longer needs one.